# Compare type of a variable

Tags: python, types

I have a variable x and whose type is :

```
type(x)
>> <class '__main__.XmlListConfig'>
```

in the next part, I want to see if the type of x is `<class'__main__.XmlListConfig'>`
I am unable to compare and see it 
So far, I have tried:

```
if type(x) == "__main__.XmlListConfig":
```

This does not work because ofcourse I am comparing it to a string. 
Any Suggesting will help and please feel free to ask me for more clarification.

Comment: Look at the type's `__name__` attribute. This is a terrible code smell, though, because it removes what little type safety Python provides.

Comment: `isinstance(x, XmlListConfig)` - or, in the unlikely event you want an exact type check rather than accepting subclasses: `type(x) is XmlListConfig`.

Comment: more info about `isinstance` and `type`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Answer (score 1):

To get around the string comparison problem you could try

```
if str(type(x)) == "<class '__main__.XmlListConfig'>":
    do_stuff()
```

although that is inconsistent and hard to read, so better to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(x, XmlListConfig):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: The first one is not only a terrible idea, it doesn't work, either, because `"<class '__main__.XmlListConfig'>"` is not equal to `"__main__.XmlListConfig"`.

Comment: @abarnert good catch, I've edited to reflect it